# Oracle: Roles, Tables, Privileges as Matrix

Tags: oracle, matrix, roles, privileges

In Oracle there is a view called role_tab_privs
which details table privileges granted to roles.
It has rows like this (not all columns displayed):

```
Table       Role        Privilege

table1      role1       SELECT
table1      role1       UPDATE
table2      role1       INSERT
```

I would like to be able to display this as a matrix, as follows:

```
Role: role1

Table     SELECT     INSERT      UPDATE     DELETE      ALTER      EXECUTE

table1     YES        YES         YES        NO          NO         NO
table2     YES         NO          NO        NO          NO         NO
etc.
```

I am not certain how to do this in sql.

A further complication is that role grants can be hierarchical,
such that if ROLE B is granted to ROLE A, role B has
all of ROLE A's privileges. In the context of the above
report, to get a complete list one would have to recursively 
traverse the role hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

hi ur answer goes here

```
SELECT role,TABLE_NAME,
       DECODE(PRIVILEGE,'SELECT','YES','NO') "SELECT",
       DECODE(PRIVILEGE,'INSERT','YES','NO') "INSERT",
       DECODE(PRIVILEGE,'UPDATE','YES','NO') "UPDATE",
       DECODE(PRIVILEGE,'DELETE','YES','NO') "DELETE",
       DECODE(PRIVILEGE,'ALTER','YES','NO') "ALTER",
       DECODE(PRIVILEGE,'EXECUTE','YES','NO') "EXECUTE"
FROM role_tab_privs
ORDER BY role;
```